# Send admin-new-order e-mail, if woocommerce order has items from a specific product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

How to send "admin new order e-mail" additionally in cc to office@mydomain.com when new order has products from category id = "99" ?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this should do the trick:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers','stack_overflow_add_cc_to_new_order_email',10,4 );

function stack_overflow_add_cc_to_new_order_email( $header, $mail_id, $mail_obj, $wc_email ) {
    if ( $mail_id == "new_order" ) {
        $header .= "Cc: Name <your@email.com>" . "\r\n"; // del if not needed
    }
    
    return $header;
}
```

The explanation is simple, everytime a WC email is sent the **woocommerce_email_headers** is called. Inside that filter you gain access to the "id" of the email (the way wc distinguish the emails) so you can check if it's the new_order email and if so add the corrisponding header to the email.

I didn't test the code but it should work. Place that code inside your theme function.php file

Comment: Sorry, but dont work: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function stack_overflow_add_cc_to_new_order_email()

Comment: ops sorry, updated the answer. Should work now. Was missing the 2 more parameters for add_filter which are priority and number of arguments. Since the custom function has 4 parameters you have to add "10,4" where 10 is the default priority and 4 is the magic number

Comment: @Nero does that work for you with the new update? if yes, accept the answer please